# Error "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable" when accessing my external hard disk

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive, filesystem-corruption

I have Windows XP SP3. I was copying files from my [ADATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADATA) 500 GB external hard disk (via USB 2.0) when a "Delayed Write Failed" error came up.

Now I am unable to access it and it gives the error:

> The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable

Answer (score -1):

Right-click on the drive in My Computer, select **Properties**, and under the **Tools** tab, click **Check Now...**.  Set the **Automatically fix file system errors** check box, then click Start.

This will scan the hard drive for errors.  If the check needs to be scheduled for the next boot, do so and restart the computer, leaving the drive plugged in; the system will perform the check on the next boot.  If any errors are detected (which it should), `CHKDSK` will fix them as possible.

For more information on how to check for errors in a disk file system, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315265.

**Edit:** Since you indicated that `CHKDSK` failed, you may be able to recover data using an application such as [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).  If not, your hard disk may have experienced damage and will need to be serviced; if this is the case, you may want to consider bringing it to a data-recovery service (which can be expensive) before you do so.

Comment: The window just closes after clicking Start. Doing a checkdisk gives only this: The type of the file system is NTFS. Unable to determine volume version and state.  CHKDSK aborted.

Disk Management says its status is Healthy, but shows 100% free space. I'm worried that my files are already gone. Anything else? Thanks for trying.

Answer (score -1):

Try [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm).

> SpinRite now brings its legendary data recovery and drive maintenance magic to the latest file systems, operating systems, and hard drives. It runs MUCH faster than ever before, can help maintain all of your drives in tip top shape, can warn of impending disaster, and wrestle data from dying and nearly dead drives . . . before it's too late.

Comment: This sounds like an advertisement for a controversial tool. Many in the data recovery industry consider it snake-oil.